# Rasa Stack Dynamic Entites

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Can we extract dynamic entities that we not defined in the nlu file or data file?

Below is my NLU File

intent:benename
ahsan
ali
ahsan
mohsin
ahmed
qaseem
yasir
qaiser
salman
daniyal

For example: above bene_names are easily extract by nlu engine, but what if when user enter a new name? how we can get that name?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough data, it *should* be able to extract the entity. (In my own personal experience though, since we had little data to work with, it didn't correctly predict the entity unless it was used in the dataset at least once.)

You can read more about it in the docs here: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#crfentityextractor

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes the above approach is good for enough data, but  i handle this by adding  the balance training data, dynamic enitity works perfectly.